# Meteor Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-accounts

I use Meteor.js and I want to customize the reset password email body. I need to insert html code in the message body. I can do this with the following code:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html = function (user, url) {
    return //html-code here
};
```

But how do I insert text from a separate file?

Comment: Can you clarify? In this function you can do whatever you want. You can render a template if you wish. What do you want to do in order to get the output string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [meteorhacks:ssr](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr) package to perform *Server Side Rendering* of templates (i.e. a separate file) into your email body.

Write your html content inside the `/private` directory, for example:

```
<!-- file: private/forgotPassword.html -->
Dear <b>{{username}}</b>,<br/>
Please click on this link to reset your password<br/>
{{url}}
```

Then load it like this:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html = function (user, url) {
  SSR.compileTemplate('forgotPassword', Assets.getText('forgotPassword.html'));
  return SSR.render("forgotPassword", { username: user.username, url: url });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for example! One more question: can I include my html-file with the css-file?

Comment: You can't really use a linked css file in email so there's no point. You have to put your css definitions in your html file. https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/